# `onChange` and `onKeyDown` in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Table = React.createClass({
.............
.............         
            handleChange: function(e) {
                switch (e.target.name) {
                case 'textarea':
                    if (this.state.newContent && this.state.newContent.trim().split('\n').length < 7) {
                        this.setState({newContent: e.target.value}); break;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    console.error('Error in handleChange()'); break;
                }
            },

            onKeyDown: function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
                    this.setState({newContent: e.target.value});
                }
            },



    .....
    <textarea type="text"
                        name="textarea"
                        value={this.state.newContent}
                        placeholder="Enter content here..."
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown} />
    ......
    .......
});
```

I'd like to have a textarea that would accept only 6 lines of input. When I enter 6 lines into the textarea and then press Backspace or Delete buttons, the `setState` does not get triggered, i.e. no character is deleted. How should i change the `handleChange` and `onKeyDown` functions so i could enter max 6 lines into the textarea and was able to remove characters from it too ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to limit this just using the `handleChange` function. Instead of checking `this.state.newContent` you should check the number of new lines in `e.target.value` (and remove `trim()`) as shown below in the runnable snippet:

```js
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newContent: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6'
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.value ||
      e.target.value.split('\n').length < 7
    ) {
      this.setState({
        newContent: e.target.value
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
     return <textarea type="text"
        className="textarea"
        name="textarea"
        value={this.state.newContent}
        placeholder="Enter content here..."
        onChange={this.handleChange}
     />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TextArea /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.textarea {
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

**EDIT**
Here is your code with these changes.

```
const Table = React.createClass({
  .............
  .............
  handleChange: function(e) {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case 'textarea':
        if (!e.target.value ||
          e.target.value.split('\n').length < 7
        ) {
          this.setState({
            newContent: e.target.value
          });
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.error('Error in handleChange()');
        break;
    }
  },

  .....         
  <textarea type="text"
    name="textarea"
    value={this.state.newContent}
    placeholder="Enter content here..."
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
  ......
  .......
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this within the same component without creating a new one ?? All my provided code is inside `const Table = React.createClass({...`

Comment: Surely, you can just take the contents of the `handleChange` function and remove the `onKeyPress` function from the `textarea`. I only put it like the above so that you can run it in this answer. However, `React.creatClass` has been deprecated from the `React` library in newer versions.

Comment: @sss See EDIT, I have applied the changes to your code, I would have thought that you could have been able to do that from my original answer though.

Comment: thanks I figured out that issue based on your reply earlier; I'd accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the handleChange and onKeyDown functions? If not, you should try adding the following lines in the constructor:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.onKeyDown= this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Can i have `this.handleChange.bind(this);` somewhere else but not in constructor? Because I have `const Table = React.createClass({`